# Método post Angular a PHP

Tags: angular, php7, post, crud

Hola ando intentando hacer un crud de angular con php y estoy intentado hacer un post a php para ver si me envía los datos pero cada que mando a llamar al método enviar me sale el error HttpErrorResponse.

**Mi código para el Post**

```
insertarProducto(producto: productos): Observable<productos>{
    return this.http.post<productos>(this.URL3, JSON.stringify(producto));
}
```

**Mi archivo Ts**

```
inventario: productos = {
    NProducto: 'Vainilla late',
    CantidadComprada: 300,
    Precio: 300,
    Total: 300
}

constructor( private api: ApiService ) { }

ngOnInit(): void {}

guardarProductos() {
 this.api.insertarProducto(this.inventario).subscribe((invent: productos) => {
    console.log(invent);
 });
}
```

Y por ultimo este es el codigo que uso en PHP para recibir el JSON

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); 
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
$payload = file_get_contents('php://input');
var_dump($payload);
json_decode($payload);
var_dump($payload);
?>
```

pero a la hora de ejecutar el metodo en el html me salta el siguiente error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya llevo un rato intentado y la verdad ya no se que mas se puede hacer no se si alguien podría proporcionarme alguna idea de como solucionar mi problema, de ante mano gracias.

Comment: Angular espera recibir una respuesta con formato JSON valido. Revisa que `prueba.php` retorne un valor válido.

Comment: Revisando la imagen, hay un `string(77)` que se esta mandando con el texto. Debes eliminarlo para que sea un JSON valido. Desconozco sobre php y por que esta haciendo eso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es un error común entre aplicaciones.

debes habilitar los CORS en tu backend, agrega las siguientes lineas donde sea correspondiente

```php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');

header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With");
```

> Verifica si vas a usar otros métodos como PUT o DELETE para que los agregues también.